# How to identify artifacts which are used multiple times

Tags: ibm-doors

I need to see a list of all artifacts in DOORS Next Generation which are used multiple times in the same module. Some users took shortcuts and reused artifacts such as headings and text artifacts that had common text in it, such as "this section was intentionally left blank."
For example, in Module A:
Artifact 12345 says "This section was intentionally left blank."
A user went in to Module A and inserted artifact 12345 every time there was no content for a particular section. So artifact 12345 appears 11 times in Module A.

Why do I need to fix this?
This creates two problems:
1. When Section 1.1.1.1 has some content in it, the user might edit artifact 12345, not knowing that that content is going to be repeated in every other section where 12345 is used.
2. When the file is output to Word or csv, there are multiple parents for artifact 12345 so the output file either omits the extra instances of artifact 12345 or repeats artifact 12345 multiple times under the first parent binding.

In the module view, I have tried using the "Used in Modules" column. This tells me if it is used in more than one module, which can be helpful. But it doesn't tell me how many times it was used or if it was reused in the same module. I can do a hover over to get a pop up that tells me. I'm wondering if there is a way to do a find and have it jump me to the artifact that is reused. For example:
Find
IF Artifact appears >1 in current module THEN locate/stop here.

A report or find function that shows me the artifact that appears in the same module more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to export a module view that includes id to a spreadsheet, then use Excel to highlight duplicates of id.